# Copy animation from rig to rig

Tags: animation, rigging

i have a character rig animated. I tried to "copy and paste" in curve editor the animation from rig to another one but seems not to be the way.

How can i transfer animation from a rig to another?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the two rigs have the same structure? Same bones names, etc? If not, I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: Yes. in this case they are exactly the same.

Comment: whoa! @SottoZen I didn't know you came here! I love you stuff.

Comment: Hey..thank you so much! I just discovered this site and i think it's really great. It helped me so much! I hope one day i can also give my little contribute to others :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If (and only if) both rigs have the same structure, with same bones naming, so you can:

- Select the first animated rig.
- In the **dope sheet** window, choose **Action Editor** context, in drop-down menu at the bottom:
  [image]
- Just to the right, there is an **Action browser** that allows you to choose the current animation of the selected object. Here you can name your action properly, to find it easily later.
  [image]
- Select the second rig, then in click on the left button of this Action browser to display all existing actions, and select in the list the one you named before.

And that's it! Your second rig should have exactly the same animation as the first one.

Be aware that if you change something in the first rig's animation, it will also change the second's one, since they share the same action. To avoid this, you can click on the "2" button (or any number that shows the number of users you have for the action) to make a single-user copy of the action and have two independent actions:

[image]

Comment: Great!
I was not working with actions but i can easily convert my animation data to action.

Comment: Well actually in Blender EVERY animation IS an action. You just have to open the action editor to see it.

Comment: right. now i see them. Sorry i am coming from Softimage and its hard to start all over :)
Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped. Can you mark the answer as "accepted" if this solution suits your needs? Thanks.

Comment: just a small remark here: if the name is not the same, search for "batch rename" -> bones, then it will work ;)

Answer (score 10):

To build on the accepted answer:  If you want to import from a separate file, you can link and append Actions from another .blend and it will show up in the action list as described before.