# 3d model mesh with bones controlling it and same bones doing an animation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I have a 3d model with bones in it, and it controls the mesh saved as an fbx file, but I have some recorded animation that controls identical bones doing the animation. But with no mesh and when I import them both into blender I have the set of bones doing the animation and a set of bones connected to the mesh not moving. Is there a way to copy the animation to control the other set of bones?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I'm not reputable enough to comment yet, so here's what I found:

[Copy animation from rig to rig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/copy-animation-from-rig-to-rig)